# How to access the files present in the MEDIA_ROOT in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, python-django-storages

I have a file named "user_001.txt" in the MEDIA_ROOT directory. I am trying to get the file name from a View and print it on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow Naga Satya!

Firstly, let me kindly suggest you take a look at StackOverflow’s “How to write a good question” page. It is always nice to write “I need to achieve X. I have tried A and B but only got result Y from that.” and add some code you have tried to use.

Django’s `MEDIA_ROOT` setting only configures where files uploaded to a `FileField` go. If you need to print a file to console, you need its path relative to where you launch manage.py from. After that it is just standard Python file reading. Check out [this GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/) tutorial about reading files.